# Certificate of net worth

Tags: india, trading

Why is it that in India a certificate of net worth is required to open a trading account? Why do the tax authorities need to know what one's net worth is in order for one to be able to open a trading account? Shouldn't they be just concerned about taxing dividends and capital gains?